# How to add website hit counter for specific website

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, hitcounter

I want to add website hit counter for my website. I am doing this in bootstrap 3.3.7, html and angularjs 1.7.

I have created a simple style and code. It works fine and it counts 35 users as a static text. How can I pass actual value here to count number of users visited my site. For testing purposes we can use some generic website.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card-counter info">
        <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
        <span class="count-numbers">35</span>
        <span class="count-name">Users</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.card-counter{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #DADADA;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: .3s linear all;
  }

  .card-counter.info{
    background-color: #26c6da;
    color: #FFF;
  }  


   .card-counter:hover{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 20px #DADADA;
    transition: .3s linear all;
  }


   .card-counter i{
    font-size: 5em;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }

  .card-counter .count-numbers{
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 32px;
    display: block;
  }

  .card-counter .count-name{
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    top: 65px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
```

JS

```
  $('.count-numbers').each(function () {
      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
          Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
          duration: 5000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function (now) {
              $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: You can't without some sort of back end piece that counts visitors for you.

Comment: I see online provides many hit counters. can we use that to get a value and show in this box

Comment: Yes, and they use some kind of server-side data persistence to keep track of visitors.  There is no way to do this with front-end alone.

Comment: How to get value from http://www.hitwebcounter.com/ and show this count in my style

Comment: Hit counters were cool 10 years ago, not now.